# How to get preferences from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, preferences

i am wanna get string from my preferences file to fragment activity. for the other activity i use code like this:

```
        String fcmToken = Preferences.getFcmToken(getBaseContext());
```

but in the fragment activity i can not use that.
here is my preferences code fill:

```
public class Preferences extends Application {

static final String KEY_USER_TEREGISTER ="user", KEY_PASS_TEREGISTER ="pass";
static final String KEY_USER_TOKEN = "user_token";
static final String KEY_FCM_TOKEN = "fcm_token";

public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreference(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

public static void setRegisteredUser(Context context, String username){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreference(context).edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_TEREGISTER, username);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getRegisteredUser(Context context){
    return getSharedPreference(context).getString(KEY_USER_TEREGISTER,"");
}


public static void setRegisteredPass(Context context, String password){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreference(context).edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_PASS_TEREGISTER, password);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getRegisteredPass(Context context){
    return getSharedPreference(context).getString(KEY_PASS_TEREGISTER,"");
}

public static void setUserToken(Context context, String token){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreference(context).edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_TOKEN,token);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getUserToken(Context context){
    return getSharedPreference(context).getString(KEY_USER_TOKEN, "");
}

public static void setFcmToken(Context context, String token){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreference(context).edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_FCM_TOKEN,token);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getFcmToken(Context context){
    return getSharedPreference(context).getString(KEY_FCM_TOKEN, "");
}

public static void clearLoggedInUser (Context context){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreference(context).edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

can you guys please how to do in fragment activity or my preferences code must to change?

Comment: How exactly does the issue sound? Could you please describe the phrase `i can not use that`? Because you can access your `Application` from a `FragmentActivity`. But, honestly, your `Application` class is already bad designed. You shouldn't use it for these purposes. `SharedPreferences` management should be done in a separate place

Comment: You should be able to just use `Preferences.getFcmToken(getActivity());` in a fragment - but this is definitely a strange pattern to have. Better to put the Preferences as its own class - not one that extends Application.

Comment: @aspix can you please tell me the example good design code